# link to image containing spaces in filename

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In my Grails app I have various images:

```
/web-app/images/competition/foo bar.png
/web-app/images/competition/foo bar2.png
/web-app/images/competition/foo bar3.png
```

The name of the image to be displayed is stored in the model that's passed to the GSP. I'm trying to create a link to this using the `<r:img>` tag provided by the resources plugin. So far I've tried:

```
<r:img file="competition/${imageName}.png"/>
<r:img file="competition/${imageName.encodeAsHTML()}.png"/>
<r:img file="competition/${imageName.encodeAsURL()}.png"/>
```

But none of these seem to work. I realise renaming the file would make my life a lot simpler, but sadly this is not possible.

Comment: Try "competition/foo%20bar.png"

Answer (score 1):

Add the below entry in `ApplicationResources.groovy` as.

```
modules = {
    images {
        resource url:'images/competition/foo%20bar.png'
    }
}
```

and access it in view as

`<r:img uri="/images/competition/foo bar.png"/>`

or

`<r:img file="competition/foo bar.png"/>`

You should be able to access the resource.

**Note:-**
Accessing the resource as
`<r:img file="competition/foo%20bar.png"/>`

did not work for me. Apparently, I made sure I am not reading from browser cache so I followed the below steps:

- Tested in Chrome Incognito Mode.
- Cleared browser cache every time.
- Tested in Firefox and IE.
- Cleaned and compiled the project to replicate the issue every time, in case browser was served from the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the reality is a little more complicated than in my original question. I've updated the question to explain the full horror of my predicament. Any further suggestions would be much appreciated.